# How To Identify the Conscrypt Source Used in Android N's Network Security Configuration Code?

Tags: android, android-source

Android N has a [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html) system for certificate pinning, self-signed certificate support (including a debug-only variant), etc. It's pretty slick. I was poking around at trying to backport it, in case Google doesn't, as it would be nice to use some of this capability on Android 6.0 and older devices.

[The source code for the network security configuration support](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/android-n-preview-3/core/java/android/security/net/config) was easy enough to find, where that link points to the `android-n-preview-3` tag.

That source refers to conscrypt, [described oh-so-helpfully](https://conscrypt.org/#) as "a Java Security Provider that uses OpenSSL."

However, the `android-n-preview-3`-tagged edition of [the conscrypt code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/) does not line up with what the network security configuration code uses. Of note, the network security configuration code relies on `TrustManagerImpl`, and the `android-n-preview-3`-tagged edition of the conscrypt code does not have that class. Earlier versions do.

I am not expert enough on the AOSP code to grok where the network security configuration code is pulling in its conscrypt implementation, so I can ensure that I am referring to the same version of that code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TrustManagerImpl is there, you can see it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/conscrypt/+/master/src/platform/java/org/conscrypt/TrustManagerImpl.java).

The Network Security Config code in AOSP is mostly up to date, but there may be changes between what's there and the final code which will be published when N is published.

Comment: Ah, it was a directory reorganization. Previously, it was in `main`, not `platform`, and I did not take the time to rummage through all locations via the Web interface. Thanks! With respect to updates, mostly what I am working on now is a recipe for how to build a backport, as that recipe would need to be applied (with modifications) for each new published version of the main code. I'm holding out slight hope for an official backport, but I'm hedging my bets, as it were. Thanks again!